# How to set transparent background to LabelField in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, label, transparent

I am trying to create a `LabelField` with no background at all, as a transparent one. I have a background set to my screen with a bitmap and I would like to have my `LabelField` transparent.

I have the following code but it does not work.

```java
BitmapField info;
EncodedImage logoBitmap = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("userInfo.png");
info = new BitmapField(null, Field.FIELD_LEFT |Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
info.setImage(logoBitmap);
AbsoluteFieldManager superMainContainer;
superMainContainer.add(info,0,200);
LabelField  nameLabel = new LabelField("Name:");
nameLabel.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0));
superMainContainer.add(nameLabel, 10, 210);
```

Answer (score 1):

*[Updated]*

Following code snippet is working on my simulator. Difference between the following one and your code is only some initialization code.

```java
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image.png");
BitmapField info = new BitmapField(bm, Field.FIELD_LEFT 
        | Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);

LabelField  lbl = new LabelField("LabelField Text");
lbl.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0));

AbsoluteFieldManager superMainContainer = new AbsoluteFieldManager();
superMainContainer.add(info, 0, 200);
superMainContainer.add(lbl, 10, 210);

MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
screen.add(superMainContainer);

UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen);
```

*[Old]*

```java
LabelField  lbl;
lbl.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0, 0));
```

You didn't initialize the `LabelField` - ***nameLabel*** before applying `Background`.

And you don't need to set any `Background` instance for getting a transparent background, the default `LabelField` will work for this case.

Comment: that's just a part of the code which i thought to be relevant.. i do initialize the label, and i know that with a simple background works, the thing is when you put a label with a bitmap field as background..

Comment: You need to paste the code you are working on. Please update your question with necessary code snippets. Also the approach you are trying to set the background seems unusual to me. You are adding a `BitmapField` to a FieldManager, why didn't you set the `Bitmap`/`EncodedImage` as `Background` of that fieldManager?

Comment: Thanks I will try to do that.. But what if I try to put a label over a bitmap field?

Comment: My problem is that I already have an image as a background, and then I add a couple of bitmapfields that come and go as you click different buttons. I need to make the labels that are over the bitmapfields that were added transparent.. But nothing seems to work

Comment: What was the output of the code snippet posted on answer? Do you just need a `BitmapField` with some text over it?

Comment: It shows the bitmapfield and the label in the correct positions, but the label has a black background that goes from the firts letter to the last letter of the label.. Between letters I cant see my image

Comment: No idea. But this code is working well and it must have to work on your simulator to. `the label has a black background that goes from the firts letter to the last letter of the label.. Between letters ` - how can you see the letters? In my code I didn't modify the LabelField. So the font color is black, and you are saying the label has black background (no background used on code). So the output have to be just a black rectangular region. I am clueless at this point. You can share the snapshot of the output.

Comment: That's because I changed the font to white.. Nevermind, I'll try something else... Thanks anyway

Comment: What code are you using to change the font color? Make sure that you are not setting background color to graphics object. Also you don't need to call graphics.clear(). Just use a code something like `protected void paint(Graphics graphics) { graphics.setColor(0xffffff); super.paint(graphics); };`.

Comment: THANKS MAN!! THAT WAS THE PROBLEM!! I called g.clear()!! really man thanks